# getting names to history page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get names for every user here and set the id as that name. I set the id of the images as the names here. Then on clicking those images i pass the name to the history.php page where using that name data is shown. But now in the window.location line items is undefined. Is this the right way to do it or is there some other standard way?

```
$.getJSON('rest.php/names', function(data) {
        var items = [];
        var recs = data.records;
        for(var i=0; i<recs.length; i++){
            items[i] = recs[i].name;
            $('#theImg').append('<img id="' + items[i] + '"' + 'src="images/Arrow-Left.png" />');
            $("img").click(function(){
                window.location = 'history3.php?name=' + items[i];
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Not a solution to your question, but move the click handler out of the for loop. You only need to bind the event once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
window.location = 'history3.php?name=' + items[i];
```

To as below and check

```
window.location = 'history3.php?name=' + $(this).attr('id');
```

*Update use `this.id` as suggested by @Neal, it will be more efficient

```
window.location = 'history3.php?name=' + this.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to this

```
$('img'+items[i]).click(function(){...}
```

or

```
window.location = 'history3.php?name=' + $(this).attr('id');
```